# Is it possible to use the back button to move between PivotItems?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Part of my app switches PivotItems automatically when a user clicks on an item in a list. I want to allow the user to press the back button after this action to switch back to the original PivotItem. How could this be achieved? If my understanding is correct the normal BackStack can only be used with pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `OnBackKeyPress()` function and set `e.Cancel` to `true` to cancel the back key press (and navigate to a different PivotItem or whatever).

However: according to the [certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> 5.2.4.1 – Back button: previous pages
>
> Pressing the Back button must return the app to the previous page or return to any previous page within the back stack.

So I wouldn't recommend doing something like this - not only is it likely to fail certification, it's also likely to confuse people.

Comment: I think you're right, I should either change the PivotItem to a new page, or forget about this altogether.